# inline css backgroundImage not showing up in react

Tags: reactjs, inline-styles, esbuild

I would like to dynamically load images from a component's props, with image assets being located in my public folder.

Image Asset:

```
public/assets/buttons/moon.jpg
```

Bundle:

```
public/bundle.js
```

Menu Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Button from './Button';

function Menu() {
  return (
    <div className="menu">
        <Button background={"#ffff44"} backgroundImage={'solarsystem'}/>
        <Button background={"#73AD21"} backgroundImage={'planet'}/>
        <Button background={"#999999"} backgroundImage={'moon'}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Button Component:

```
import React from 'react';

class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {

        const buttonStyle = {
            backgroundImage: `('./assets/buttons/${this.props.backgroundImage}.jpg')`,
            background: this.props.background
        }

        return (
            <div style={buttonStyle} className="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Button;
```

I have tried different paths:

```
assets/buttons/moon.jpg
/assets/buttons/moon.jpg
./assets/buttons/moon.jpg
```

I have tried to use **require** but I get an error.

```
bundle.js:14 Uncaught Error: Dynamic require of "('./assets/buttons/planet.jpg')" is not supported
```

I intend to be loading from a s3 bucket eventually.